# Visual variable renderer doesn’t work on mobile

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I don’t even know where to start with this one. I have developed this simple application: http://matthewiannowlin.com/school-tax-referendum/

If you try this on a desktop, the layers will render correctly, but on a phone the color ramps are not accurate. In the picture the highlighted tract is dark purple, even though it’s median assessed value is $74k and purple is for assessed values of $300k+.

[image: This tract has median assessed value of $74k, so it should not appear dark purple.]

What about the mobile version of this site could change the way the color ramp is rendered? On my end, I have made this responsive through css, so there is nothing different about the script when you view it on a phone.

I’m using ArcGIS JavaScript api 4.9.

EDIT: Here is the code to define and change the renderer.

```
    var totAssdRenderer = { //Define Renderer: Total Assessed Value
    type: "simple",
    symbol: tractSymbol,
    label: "Neighborhoods (Census Tracts)",
    visualVariables: [{
      type: "color",
      field: "RESULT_1",
      stops: [
      {
        value: 30000000,
        color: "#FFFCD4",
        label: "$30M and below"
      },
      {
        value: 300000000,
        color: "#350242",
        label: "$300M and above"
      }]
    }]
};
...//I establish a few more of these renderers
var tractLayer = new FeatureLayer({//I build a layer using one of my renderers
    url: "https://services.arcgis.com/tKsJAIiLjd90D5q2/arcgis/rest/services/Join_Features_to_SchoolTaxReferendum/FeatureServer/0",
    renderer: medAssdRenderer,
    outFields: ["*"],
    popupTemplate: template,
    opacity:0.5
});
var map = new Map({ //build a map using that layer
    basemap: "gray",
    layers: [tractLayer, districtLayer]
});
changeRenderer = function(chosenRenderer,title,idString) {//on button click, I call this function to apply the renderer defined by the button
    tractLayer.renderer = eval(chosenRenderer);
    document.getElementById("tools").className = "";
    document.getElementById("chooseVariable").innerHTML = title + "<span class='action'>Change</span>";
    chosenRendererLabel = title;
    revealMenuToggle = 0;
    var i;
    legendButtonsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("legendButton");
    for (i=0; i < legendButtonsArray.length; i++){
        legendButtonsArray[i].className = "legendButton";
    }
    document.getElementById(idString).className = "legendButton selectedLayer";
};
```

Comment: Which phone/browser are you using? I am not seeing a difference between mobile and desktop.

Comment: I'm using an iPhone with iOS 12. Tested on chrome and safari.